# Create a condition between these two fields

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table

I'm trying to create a condition where QGIS understands that if "connections = None" then "number of connections = 0". How can I do this?

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Try this: `if("connections" = 'None', 0, "connections")`

Comment: Where should I apply the condition?

Comment: Or proabably be `if("connections" is Null, 0, "connections")`. Apply this in your field calculator in your attribute table.

Comment: Hmm, But I intend that if I select "não" in the left column he automatically puts "0" in the right column, I tried that code but he just added a new value called (1).

Comment: What you wrote basically changes every "NULL" elements to "0", right?

Comment: I want it basically that every time I select the option "Não" (that is the same as "No", left column of the image), Qgis automatically sets the option on "number of connections" (right column of the image) to "0"

Comment: @Mayo Hmm ok ok, then I'll try to play it with "Não".